# Different Objects, same name variable should have two different values but doesn't?

Tags: java, debugging, variables, object

PURPOSE: Take User Input of Name and Age and print a message at the end that says:

"Name is Age."

NameIsAge.java

```
public class NameIsAge 
{
    static String userName;
    static int userAge;
    NameIsAge (String userName, int userAge)
    {
        userName = this.userName;
        userAge = this.userAge;

    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public int getUserAge() {
        return userAge;
    }
    public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }
    final void run(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(userName + " is " + userAge);
    }
}
```

NameIsAgeLauncher.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public final class NameIsAgeLauncher {
    private NameIsAgeLauncher() 
    {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userName = null;
        int userAge = 0;
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name: "); //Prompts user to enter name.
        NameIsAge.userName = stdIn.nextLine(); //Name from Practice should be equal to what the user enters.
        System.out.println("Enter your age: "); //Prompts user to enter name.
        NameIsAge.userAge = stdIn.nextInt(); //Name from Practice should be equal to what the user enters.
        NameIsAge blah = new NameIsAge(userName, userAge);

        NameIsAge halb = new NameIsAge ("Campbell", 97);
        halb.setUserName("Campbell");
        halb.setUserAge (97);
        System.out.println(blah.userName + " is " + blah.userAge + ".");
        System.out.println(halb.userName + " is " + halb.userAge + ".");
    }   
}
```

This prints this:

```
Enter your name: 
dsf
Enter your age: 
32
Blah: Campbell is 97.
Halb: Campbell is 97.
```

It should print this:

```
Blah: dsf is 32.
Halb: Campbell is 97.
```

Y does setting the value for halb change blah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is caused by static modificators.

```
static String userName;
static int userAge;
```

removing the static keywords is the trick
Static modificators indicates it is for all instances.
Btw. the constructor is bad, should be:

```
NameIsAge (String userName, int userAge)
{
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userAge = userAge;

}
```

Folows the whole code:
Try to use local variable for auxiliary variables

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public final class NameIsAgeLauncher {
private NameIsAgeLauncher() 
{
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userName = null;
    int userAge = 0;
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: "); //Prompts user to enter name.
    userName = stdIn.nextLine(); //Name from Practice should be equal to what the user enters.
    System.out.println("Enter your age: "); //Prompts user to enter name.
    userAge = stdIn.nextInt(); //Name from Practice should be equal to what the user enters.
    NameIsAge blah = new NameIsAge(userName, userAge);

    NameIsAge halb = new NameIsAge ("Campbell", 97);
    halb.setUserName("Campbell");
    halb.setUserAge (97);
    System.out.println(blah.userName + " is " + blah.userAge + ".");
    System.out.println(halb.userName + " is " + halb.userAge + ".");
}   
}
```

.

```
public class NameIsAge 
{
String userName;
int userAge;
NameIsAge (String userName, int userAge)
{
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userAge = userAge;

}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public int getUserAge() {
    return userAge;
}
public void setUserAge(int userAge) {
    this.userAge = userAge;
}
final void run(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(userName + " is " + userAge);
}
}
```

Comment: So after I remove the static keywords it gives this error in the launcher:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field NameIsAge.userName

Comment: You are now using a instance variables as static, wh won'ty you use local variables @Dasman, my answer was edited

Comment: This works well! I just uhad a small follow up. I'm new to Java.

So with halb - I declare new NameIsAge ("Campbell", 97);
BUT then why do I have to do the two setUserName and setUserAge lines? Haven't I already initialized with the new declare statement.

Comment: Yes, you are right, these lines redeclaring already declared variables, I just copied your code and corrected it ;). So these statements could be removed